# Set keyboard cursor at the end of text ios Flutter

Tags: flutter, keyboard

I want to put the keyboard cursor at the end. There are two methods, but they work only in Android devices not iOS. I tried this one

```
comment_control.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: comment_control.text.length);
```

and this one

```
comment_control.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: comment_control.text.length));
```

They work only in Android devices and not in iOS like iphone. In ios cursor puts at the beginning when I use these to methods

How to fix this problem? is there another method?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Flutter team have fixed this bug in Flutter version 2.0.1.
You can use my code above, it works now.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try This:

```
onChanged: (text) {
   TextSelection previousSelection = controller.selection;
   controller.text = text;
   controller.selection = previousSelection;
}
```

Comment: I tested that, I got same problem